# I am creating an Ubuntu desktop and will do internet banking. Do I need VPN and antivirus?

Tags: security

The machine will be used with Libreoffice and Firefox and Duckduckgo for browsing.

I want to know I'm secure when accessing may bank accounts and making credit card payments.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The same rules when using money online apply regardless of operating system. Be sure the browser shows a lock next to the site address, as this shows SSL is being used. Always verify the URL when entering credentials. If something doesn’t *feel* right then stop, close the browser tab, and start again 

Comment: No mention of Tor, Tails or Full Disk Encryption?

Answer (score 1):

With all these things -you- are the first and best protection. Do not do stupid things are you are fine.

Regarding AV:

You never need antivirus on Linux systems unless you use Windows and want an extra layer before files get to your Window desktop. The bigger threat for Linux servers are root kits but as with any of these threats: it will not work if it does not gain admin permissions. So generally: use a good password, don't type your password unless you expect it to be asked and it negates most of the problems related to these kind of issues.

As of today the Linux/Ubuntu security system has not been cracked. Individual systems might get hacked or infested (and most of the time those are servers that are badly configured or where an admin uses 12345 as a password) but generally it requires someone targeting you specifically. It is still  not possible to infect thousands of systems by releasing a script; like it is possible on Windows. Part of this is that Linux users also tend to be better educated on using computers and using the web.

Regarding banking:

Generally banks do not advice you to use a VPN so that should be a 1st indicator it is not really needed. It might even be bad: a VPN rotates locations so a bank might lock you out when it sees you log in from South America when you are in Europe.

A https connection to your bank's website should be enough. Where I live you also need a device (an e-identifier with your bank card or a phone with fingerprint login) to do as an extra check for every transaction you want to execute. That is more than enough.

Regarding VPN:

It is not a bad idea to use one generally, so not specific to banking. Opera has one built in in case you need one inside a browser. VPNs only protect against 3rd parties: your VPN provider is a "man in the middle" that can see any traffic that is not encrypted before you send it out. So make sure the VPN owner can sort of be trusted.

Comment: I believe Opera "is not" Opera any more, since long ago... I believe Vivaldi "is" Opera, isn't that the case?

Comment: The only purpose a VPN really serves is to disguise the traffic between the client and VPN server, and it doesn't even do a great job of that on its own if your software is sending DNS requests unencrypted.  It can be useful if you are on a public or shared network where someone could inspect the packets you send and receive. You also give a lot of power to your VPN provider as they essentially become your ISP and *they* can see all of your unencrypted traffic as well as quite a large amount of metadata concerning encrypted traffic.

Comment: vivaldi is a chromium clone (it uses blink as an layout engine)

Comment: What I meant is the episode when the Opera browser got sold to an intransparent investor, and a large number of the developers quit in protest (publicized on Twitter), many of whom started/joined the Vivaldi project. I guess that explains why they use Chromium; they did not have the capacity to start from scratch again. And what is meaningful in this is why did those developers feel the need to quit their jobs and start job-searching on Twitter after the acquisition...